# WIFI connecting on old standard rather than wifi5 that it supports

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a dell xps15 running ubuntu 22.04 (up to date). It connects to my wifi network as a wifi2 (standard) connection when I boot up. If I boot the ubuntu live cd (ubuntu 22.04 version), it logs into my network as a wifi5 (standard) connection. How do I troubleshoot the reason that it is connecting on an older standard than the newer standard it supports?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind. I found the problem. I had add an option in the iwlwifi.conf an option
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
I do not know why but this was the problem.